# Prove that the measure of the set is equal to the measure of intersection of its members

Tags: measure-theory

Given any set $ A \subseteq \mathbb R $, there is a set $G$ that contains $A$ such that 
$$ G = \cap _ {i=1} ^ \infty A_i $$ 
with each $A_i$ open and $m*(G) = M*(A).

Here is my approach so far:

Since the set $G$ contains $A$, $A \subseteq G$ and that implies that $ m^* (A) \le M^* (G) $. But I got stuck to show $ M^*(G) \le m^*(A)$.

Any hints or suggestion are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to construct such a $G$. My suggestion is to show that there exists open sets $A_n$ such that $A \subset A_n$ and $m^*(A) \leq m^{*}(A_n) \leq m^*(A)+\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Then $m^*(G) \leq m^*(A_n)$ for all $n$, which would imply the equality you are after.

Comment: So to show the statement you gave, can i just write that down since existence of open set $A_i$ is given? Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Well if the existence of the open sets $A_i$ with this property is given, then you are done- as I noted above :).

Comment: Thanks a lot! the question states each $A_i$ is open, so I think I am done.